# How to initialise state with useState hook and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

State will be updated using the `useState` hook with an array of objects at some point in the future which has an interface that looks like this:

```js
export interface DataSource {
  dataPiont: Array<DataPoint>;
}

export interface DataPoint {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

I have the hook set up where I have to initialise state:

```js
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<DataSource>([{ key: '' }]);
```

But I am getting the Typescript error `"Argument of type '{ key: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DataSource | (() => DataSource)'.`

I don't want to add `null` or `undefined` or `[]` to my interface as I have to use it throughout the application.

How can I successfully initialise state in this instance?

Comment: How does an object of type 'DataPoint' look like? If it is `{ key: '' }` then its interface should be `export interface DataPoint {
  key:  string | number;
}`

Comment: `{      age: `Item ${idx}`,
      name: item.title.substring(1, 16),
      location: item.body.substring(1, 16),
      error: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1),}`

Comment: Either pass in a dummy object of the above mentioned object. Or you could: `useState<DataSource | undefined>(undefined);` which would be better to understand for someone else to read.

Comment: dataPoint is misspelled as dataPiont in the first interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `DataSource` has `dataPiont` object key. Maybe you want to use the interface `Array<DataPoint>` for state?

```
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<Array<DataPoint>>([]);
```